# What is happening when there is a conversion between types in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I have to convert a VB.NET String variable into a type of SqlChars (a built-in VB.NET type).

The code I am using is:

```
Dim sqlPolyStr As String
sqlPolyStr = "POLYGON((" & ptsStr & "))"
Dim sqlChrsPoly As New SqlChars(sqlPolyStr)
```

The code works fine, I just wondered if there is a name for the process of conversion between types that is taking place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I know what you're talking about, this isn't a great example because that's not quite converting the object, it is using a constructor and that constructor is doing stuff in the background.

A better example is `dim a as integer = cType("12345", integer)` This process is known as typecasting and [more details can be found here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4x2877xb.aspx). My example is still poor because in vb.net you can still do `dim a as integer = "12345"` but it's a start for you.

The example you gave uses the constructor. Whoever programmed "SqlChars" made a constructor that accepts type `String` by making a sub such as

```vb
Public Sub New(ByVal str as string)
   ' DO something here with the string to make a SqlChars object
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused about why a direct conversion from String to SqlChars wasn't working but the example I have given does and wanted to research more into the subject but didn't really know where to begin.